# Intel 8051 UART mode 0 doesn't work in Proteus (clock impulses on TXD occur constantly, MCU recieves bytes itself)

Tags: uart, 8051

I think that I've read everything about 8051's UART but I can't understand what goes wrong even in this simpliest example. According to literature in mode 0 MCU transmits byte only when we write it into SBUF, and only there 8 clock impulses occur in TXD line; MCU reads byte when TXD voltage changes.
In this example (only indicator is connected to P1) I write nothing to SBUF, but pediodically TI, then RI interrpupt occur, TXD voltage constantly changes and I constantly recieve 0.
Clock frequency is 12 MHz. What can be a reason?
Thank everyone for any effort!

```
;====================================================================
; MCU: 80C51
; Compiler:  ASEM-51 (Proteus)
;====================================================================

$NOMOD51
$INCLUDE (8051.MCU)

;====================================================================
; RESET AND INTERRUPT VECTORS
;====================================================================

      ; Reset vector
      org   0000h
      jmp   Init

      ; Serial port interrupt vector
      org   0023h
      call  SERIAL_PORT_HANDLER
      reti

;====================================================================
; MAIN CODE BLOCK
;====================================================================

      org   0150h
Init:   
      setb  ES
      setb  EA
      mov   SCON,       #00010000b ; UART Mode 0,
                       ; accept messages with any 9th bit,
                       ; enable recieving,
                       ; don't recieve 9th bit, 
                       ; clear interrupt flags

Loop:
      jmp   Loop

;====================================================================
; SERIAL PORT INTERRUPT HANDLER
;====================================================================      

SERIAL_PORT_HANDLER:
   jb       TI,     _SENT

_RECEIVED:
   mov      P1, SBUF ; Move to indicator
   clr      RI
   jmp      _AFTER_SERIAL_PORT_HANDLING

_SENT:
   clr      TI

_AFTER_SERIAL_PORT_HANDLING:
   ret

;====================================================================
      END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constant impulses in TXD line are likely a glitch of Proteus. I have reassembled this scheme in NI Multisim and there MCUs with the same firmware generate clock impulses on TXD pin properly, only when writing to SBUF.
What about recieving byte - as I understood it just begins when RE=1 and RI=0.

Answer (score 2):

Did you leave the UART input pin open circuit? If so it is probably looking like an occasional start bit due to noise pickup.

Comment: Yes, I did so in this example, but originally I connected two MCUs with the same microcode - RXD to RXD and TXD to TXD and result was the same.

Comment: i think you should cross connect two MCUs RXD to TXD and TXD to RXD?

Comment: @Lokanath It is mode 0 (synchronous), there TXD is clock source/reciever and RXD is data source/reciever. As I understand 8 clock impulses must occur on TXD pin only when MCU transmits data but in my case they occur all the time.

Comment: TXD is output, RXD is input, you must connect input to output. (This is the most common mistake people make with this interface.)

Comment: @MarkU Please be attentive before answering. It is true for modes 1-3 but in mode 0 RXD is both input and output. http://nptel.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT-KANPUR/microcontrollers/micro/ui/Course_home2_11.htm

Comment: Okay, maybe TXD always generates clock impulses, not only during transmitting. But my problem is still open - MCU always recieves something. Of course I can check recieved byte for equality with 0xFF and ignore it if it is so. But then I will not be able to recieve truly transmitted 0xFF. Is there any better way to solve thу problem?